# Using DBT, Unable to insert data from one SQLite Database to another SQLite Database

Tags: sqlite, dbt

I am trying to move data between two SQLite Databases as my first project.
I have three tables in my first SQLite DB, which contains few records (1-2 records)

I am trying to copy these records into my target SQLite database.
I am able to run my models, which run successfully and they also create new identical tables in my second Database. But no data gets copied. I have tried so many ways but it still doesn't work for me.

my **profiles.yaml** file,

```
local_sqlite_project:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      type: sqlite
      threads: 1
      database: 'database'
      schema: 'main'
      schemas_and_paths:
        main: 'C:/Programming/Projects/dbt/target.db'
      schema_directory: 'file_path'
      #optional fields
#     extensions:
#       - "/path/to/sqlean/crypto.so"

# Add a new connection for your source SQLite file
  sources:
    dev:
      type: sqlite
      database: 'C:/Programming/Projects/dbt/dbt-tutorial/tutorial_project/source/source.db'
      schema: 'source'
```

My source.yaml file,

```
version: 2

sources:
  - name: sample_table_database
    database: 'source'  
    schema: 'main'
    tables:
      - name: first_table
      - name: second_table
      - name: third_table
```

My first_model.sql file (other two models are also identical with table name changed)

```
{{ config(materialized='table') }}

with source_data as (

    select ID, Name from {{ source('sample_table_database', 'first_table') }}

),

final as (
    select * from source_data
)

select * from final
```

Not sure if this is necessary but my dbt_project.yaml file is also shared here,

```
# Name your project! Project names should contain only lowercase characters
# and underscores. A good package name should reflect your organization's
# name or the intended use of these models
name: 'tutorial_project'
version: '1.0.0'
config-version: 2

# This setting configures which "profile" dbt uses for this project.
profile: 'local_sqlite_project'

# These configurations specify where dbt should look for different types of files.
# The `model-paths` config, for example, states that models in this project can be
# found in the "models/" directory. You probably won't need to change these!
model-paths: ["models"]
analysis-paths: ["analyses"]
test-paths: ["tests"]
seed-paths: ["seeds"]
macro-paths: ["macros"]
snapshot-paths: ["snapshots"]

target-path: "target"  # directory which will store compiled SQL files
clean-targets:         # directories to be removed by `dbt clean`
  - "target"
  - "dbt_packages"


# Configuring models
# Full documentation: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/configuring-models

# In this example config, we tell dbt to build all models in the example/
# directory as views. These settings can be overridden in the individual model
# files using the `{{ config(...) }}` macro.
models:
  tutorial_project:
    # Config indicated by + and applies to all files under models/example/
    example:
      +materialized: view
```

If you would like to see the whole Repo, you may do so here: https://github.com/hassanashas/dbt-tutorial

I have also uploaded the SQLite files, if anyone is interested in checking them out,

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PKdpffsPxAGg1f7yxNG3gHmKl6SsOFwr?usp=sharing